# Create Date from two cols in mySql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a table in my database with two columns: month (1-12) and year (yyyy).

I need to select records between two dates, for exemple

```
select * from Calendar a where SOMEDATE between STARTDATE and ENDDATE.
```

So the question is: how can I create the STARTDATE and the ENDDATE from this two columns I have?

Comment: So there is no day info?

Comment: No, there is not this info. Unnecessary.

Comment: If you no provide day, you are not comparing dates. And I can't understand why you store in separate fields two data that you need joined to compare. A best aproach is store in the same field the number  mmYYYY and compare no a date, compare a given number

Comment: Ok. Imagine the day is always 01. In this case I don't care about days because the only relevant thing is the month and the year. Why do I need to store unnecessary info?

Answer (score 1):

```
...where SOMEDATE between 
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',STARTYEAR,STARTMONTH,1),'%Y-%m-%d')
and
DATE_SUB(
    STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-',ENDYEAR,ENDMONTH + 1,1),'%Y-%m-%d')
    , INTERVAL DAY 1
)
```

Note that we convert both parts to type date, and use `date_sub` to subtract a single day from `ENDMONTH + 1`, since we don't know how many days there are in the relevant month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to make date from the `year` and `month` fields-

```
SELECT MAKEDATE(year, 1) + INTERVAL month - 1 MONTH FROM calendar;
```

The apply this one to WHERE condition, e.g. -

```
SELECT * FROM Calendar a
WHERE
  MAKEDATE(year, 1) + INTERVAL month - 1 MONTH BETWEEN
    @STARDATE - INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAY FROM @STARDATE) - 1 DAY
    AND
    @ENDDATE
```

But I have to ask you about the STARTDATE and ENDDATE criterias. What to do if STARTDATE is '2012-09-20'? Should the query return records with month = 9?